# Firebase serve command gives HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am a beginner on Firebase, I got a error when write command line "firebase serve".On the other hand, I can run "firebase deploy" command.Is this problem about OAuth 2.0 authentication ?

I am not developing ios, android app. I have been doing web site.

CLI Version:   3.18.4 , Platform:      win32, Node Version:  v8.11.1

```
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.420Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.423Z] Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ahmet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase serve
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.423Z] CLI Version:   3.18.4
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.423Z] Platform:      win32
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.423Z] Node Version:  v8.11.1
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.423Z] Time:          Fri May 04 2018 07:00:08 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.423Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [debug] 
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.432Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.432Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.434Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.434Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
     { refresh_token: '1/p1W5jdYn4PPSS0uPOTQt4K7qd_uw138yP26juNljNdPQ',
      client_id: '56358434335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pd03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      client_secret: 'j9idda34334fs',
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase openid' } 
     Fri May 04 2018 07:00:08 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.780Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:08.787Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/database  

     Fri May 04 2018 07:00:08 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:09.878Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:09.880Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/database/tokens  

     Fri May 04 2018 07:00:09 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:10.761Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:10.764Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/database  

     Fri May 04 2018 07:00:10 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:11.902Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
    [info] 
    [info] === Serving from 'C:\Projects\projectname'...
    [info] 
    [info] i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:13.307Z] Fetching environment
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:13.309Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/v1/projects/330783331994:getServerAppConfig  

     Fri May 04 2018 07:00:13 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:13.309Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/v1/projects/330783331994/clients/_:getWebAppConfig  

     Fri May 04 2018 07:00:13 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:14.091Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:14.093Z] Starting @google-cloud/functions-emulator
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:14.363Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 500
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:14.363Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY
    [error] 
    [error] Error: HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered.
    [debug] [2018-05-04T04:00:14.636Z] Error Context: {
      "body": {
        "error": {
          "code": 500,
          "message": "Internal error encountered.",
          "status": "INTERNAL"
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "body": {
          "error": {
            "code": 500,
            "message": "Internal error encountered.",
            "status": "INTERNAL"
          }
        },
        "headers": {
          "vary": "X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding",
          "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          "date": "Fri, 04 May 2018 04:00:14 GMT",
          "server": "ESF",
          "cache-control": "private",
          "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
          "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
          "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
          "alt-svc": "hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"43,42,41,39,35\"",
          "accept-ranges": "none",
          "connection": "close"
        },
        "request": {
          "uri": {
            "protocol": "https:",
            "slashes": true,
            "auth": null,
            "host": "mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com",
            "port": 443,
            "hostname": "mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com",
            "hash": null,
            "search": null,
            "query": null,
            "pathname": "/v1/projects/330783331994/clients/_:getWebAppConfig",
            "path": "/v1/projects/330783331994/clients/_:getWebAppConfig",
            "href": "https://mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/v1/projects/330783331994/clients/_:getWebAppConfig"
          },
          "method": "GET"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: For general deployment errors, please open a support ticket with Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/